# Picture Intent Zero Length Image

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-photos

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to call the intent to get a picture in full size:

**takePictureIntent**

```
private void takePictureIntent(int request) {
    final Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File file = null;

        try {
            file = createImageFile(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.error_saving_picture));
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating image file.");
        }

        if (file != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, request);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating image file.");
            showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.error_saving_picture));
        }
    }
}
```

**createImageFile**

```
private File createImageFile(final int request) {
    final File storageDir = new File(activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getString(R.string.app_name));

    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create parent folders.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    File file = null;

    try {
        file = File.createTempFile("test_", ".jpg", storageDir);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating temp file.");
    }

    fileProduct = file;

    return file;
}
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_PRODUCT) {

    if (fileProduct == null ||!fileProduct.exists() ||fileProduct.length() == 0) {
        showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.error_taking_product_picture));
        return;
    }
}
```

Sometimes (yes, sometimes) the length of the resulting file is 0. I know for sure that the folders in private app context exist and the image files as well (with length > 0). Could you please provide some help? I'm on 6.0 on Nexus 5X.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by getting rid of `File.createTempFile()`. You do not need it, it wastes time, and it might cause some camera apps to want to not store the photo in that file (since the file is already there). Just generate a unique filename yourself. This will incrementally help with your compatibility.

Also, you need to make sure that you are holding onto `fileProduct` in the saved instance state `Bundle`, as your app's process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground.

However, in general, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not very reliable. You are delegating the work to one of hundreds of possible camera apps, and some of those apps have bugs. One such bug is ignoring `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. So, in `onActivityResult()`, if you determine that you have a valid `fileProduct` value, but there is no file there, call `data.getData()` and see if you have a `Uri` there. In that case, the camera app may have stored the photo at the location identified by that `Uri`, and you can use `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile` to try to work with that `Uri`.

Comment: Ok for 1 and 2, but I wouldn't expect such a bug on a Nexus camera app...This code is working fine on a Motorola Moto G 2014 with Lollipop. I'm calling startActivityForResult from a fragment if this could be helpful. What I'm not getting here, is that the image is there, filesystem has it...sob.

Comment: @Jumpa: Then your problem is not a zero-length file. My guess is that `fileProduct` is `null`, because your process was terminated in the background.

Comment: I tested it file exists (i mean the method exists()) and is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
file = new File(storageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
```

instead of

```
File.createTempFile()
```

magically seems to fix the problem. Thanks to CommonsWare for (somehow) pointing me in the right direction.